# Translate a JPEG image to NITF in C++? (maybe using GDAL?)

Tags: gdal, jpg, nitf

The following question is similar, and shows how to do translation from PNG to NITF on the linux command line using GDAL:
[Performing gdal translate to png/jpeg?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283975/performing-gdal-translate-to-png-jpeg)

I need to do something similar in C++. I have thought about using Nitro, but the licensing may not be compatible with my use case. GDAL's licensing *is* compatible with our use case, but I cannot find anything similar to `gdal_translate` in the GDAL C++ libraries. Can anyone shed some light on how I would do this?

The actual use case: Package JPEG image as NITF, and then unpackage the NITF image back to JPEG or other easily displayable format.

Comment: The normal way to convert between data formats in GDAL C++ is to open the dataset using a particular driver, then write it out to a new file using a different driver.  However, recent versions of GDAL include a 'utils' API that short cuts some of this, effectively replicating the command line utilities.  These functions are still non-trivial to use, but may still be easier than the manual open-and-save method.  See `GDALTranslate()` at:  https://gdal.org/api/gdal_utils.html#gdal__utils_8h_1a1cf5b30de14ccaf847ae7a77bb546b28

Comment: @SonofaBeach that sounds like an answer ;)